# cultivation manga / manhwa / manhua where the female lead is a doctor and married a “ monster “

Tags: story-identification, manga, cultivation

i dont entirely remember the plot but i could point out that ;

• the female lead was a researcher / doctor researching about her younger brother i believe

• she was reincarnated into a historical chinese era where she was forced to marry a “ monster “

• i remember that the “ monster “ is actually the male lead with dark hair and is so head over heels for the female lead

• in fl second life , she became a renowned doctor / someone who excels in medicine ??

• also they apparently kidnap / stole a noble ‘ s son because he was an illegitimate one ???? the noble died due to childbirth i think

• the fl kept the infant because it reminded her of her own little brother

can someone please help me find the title it had been lingering in my mind for so long and i miss reading it

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters?

Comment: i could barely remember any of the characters names since i read this years ago sorry

Comment: @qazmlpok forgive me i also do not remember when i have last read this . i have a very fuzzy memory , conflicted either its in webcomic or any other manhwa websites

Comment: Can you put a rough estimate to it? Like was it definitely before 2022? 2020? 2016?

Comment: @qazmlpok i believe i read it around 2019 to 2021

Answer (score 1):

It's a long shot but maybe [Doctor Elise: royal lady with a lamp](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/doctor-elise-the-royal-lady-with-the-lamp)?
We have female lead tho reincarnated twice. In second life she was professional doctor and in third she used this knowledge in the world of her first life. She (initially reluctantly) marries male lead who is infatuated with her and has scary renown.

Comment: sorry , it ‘ s not that one . the female lead had a dark colored hair and eyes and from the cover alone , i could tell the aesthetic of it is english nobility instead of chinese / korean . thank you for trying though